# Canon MP280 ubuntu server not printing

Tags: networking, server, printing, canon

Canon MP280 connected to ubuntu server 20.04 via usb printing correctly when print sent from linux mint laptop over network. Print sent from Arch laptop does not print. Cups on arch reports print complete. Cups on ubuntu server reports complete but printer does not respond. I have tried with various users - admin and others to no avail. Running lpq -a on server terminal shows no items in spool.
Please advise.

P.S.  Arch laptop previously printed successfully via Cups on raspberry Pi.